# Deleting duplicate data from table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table duplicate which shows datas as:

```
select * from ot.duplicate;
```

[image]

I wanted to delete the duplicate data from the table where I tried:

```
delete  from (select * from(select * from ot.duplicate a
union
select * from ot.duplicate b) t1);
```

But I am getting error:

```
ORA-01752: cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`.

```
Delete from your_table y1
Where exists (select 1 
From your_table y2
Where y1.id = y2.id
Abd y1.name = y2.name
And y1.rowid > y2.rowid);
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try below query -

```
DELETE FROM ot.duplicate A
WHERE ROWID > (SELECT MIN(ROWID)
               FROM ot.duplicate B
               WHERE A.ID = B.ID
               AND A.NAME = B.NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should have been like this in SQL Server

```
;with cte as (
select * from (
select id,name ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by name order by id) as trow from testt
) as p  
)

delete from cte where trow>1
```